# Writing R code using rep() function but not c() function to get sequence 1 1 1 1 1 2 3 3 3 4 4 4 4 5 5

Tags: r

I am trying to write the R code for this sequence "11111233344455"

I figured out how to do it with the `c()` function.

```
rep(1:5,c(5,1,3,4,2))
```

But can't figure out how to do it without it.

I've tried

```
seq(rep(1,5),1:5)
seq(rep(5,5),1:5)
```

Neither work

Comment: a brainstorming question?

Answer (score 7):

One could eliminate the usage of the c() function to produce the desired output in a fairly trivial way:

```
rep(1:5,list(5,1,3,4,2))
```

However, it's not clear exactly what you are trying to avoid here by eliminating the c() function.

Comment: What a smart workaround! +1!

Answer (score 4):

There must be many tricky ways, but the codes below are just some of them for fun (I would say, they look silly :P)

```
cumsum(
    replace(
        replace(
            replace(
                replace(
                    replace(
                        rep(0, sum(1:5)),
                        1, 1
                    ), 6, 1
                ), 7, 1
            ), 10, 1
        ), 14, 1
    )
)
```

or

```
rep(1:5, as.numeric(strsplit("51342", "")[[1]]))
```

or

```
rep(1:5, scan(text = "5 1 3 4 2"))
```

or

```
unlist(list(
    rep(1, 5),
    rep(2, 1),
    rep(3, 3),
    rep(4, 4),
    rep(5, 2)
))
```

or

```
unlist(Map(rep, 1:5, list(5, 1, 3, 4, 2)))
```

or

```
as.integer(strsplit(paste0(11111, 2, 333, 4444, 55, collapse = ""), "")[[1]])
```

Answer (score 2):

Not sure why you would do this, but you can rep the numbers so they are all the same length and then remove elements:

```r
rep(1:5, each = 5)[-(7:12)][-10][-(14:16)]
```

Or

```r
unlist(mapply(replicate, list(5, 1, 3, 4, 2), 1:5))
```

Or

```r
l <- list(5, 1, 3, 4, 2)
unlist(lapply(seq_along(l), \(x) rep(x, l[[x]])))
```

Or

```r
do.call(rep, list(1:5, list(5, 1, 3, 4, 2)))
```

I think maybe the simplest solution for writing it would be...

```r
"11111233344455"
```

Answer (score 2):

Yes, many silly ways to do that :) Such as this one:

```r
rep(1:5, utf8ToInt('51342') - 48)
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this counts as not using `c`.  It calls the internal code that `c` uses without invoking `c`.

```
rep(1:5, .Primitive("c")(5, 1, 3, 4, 2))
## [1] 1 1 1 1 1 2 3 3 3 4 4 4 4 5 5
```